I want to use Throttle in an MVC controller to control the flow rate
I'm using Tomcat's web server, and I have a process that retrieves a large amount of data. I'm trying to respond to a request from a client and only do it 5 times in 10 seconds.
For Apache camel, I'm a newbie, so I set it up as follows, but it ends as soon as the REST service is executed.
・Controller.java
@RequestMapping(value = "searchInfo" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<InfoEntity> searchInfo(@RequestParam Map<string, String> requestParam) throws  Exception{
  try(CamelContext camel = new DefaultCamelContext()) {
    camel.addRoutes(createBasicRoute());
    camel.start();
}

List<BuilEntity> infoList = infoService.getInfo(requestParam.get("id));

return infoList;
}

static RouteBuilder createBasicRoute(){
    return new RouteBuilder(){
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{
        rest("/E40101").to("direct:CamelRoute");
  
        from("direct:CamelRoute")
            .throttle(5)
            .timePeriodMillis(10000)
            .to("mock:result");
    }
 }

